# Reassigning a module's function for testing purposes

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, monkeypatching

I was considering reassigning some functions from a standard library module in my testing suite, however I have found that doing so has a global effect (when I expected them to only have an effect locally). For example:

```
import time
def test():
    time.sleep = "hello" #woah there! time is mutable so this won't just apply locally!

print time.sleep #prints <built-in function sleep>
test()
print time.sleep #prints hello (!)
```

Must I be revert `time.sleep` to what it was before at the end of `test()`?

Is this something which is **discouraged**... How *should* I be doing this kind of testing?

Comment: Why don't you save a reference to the builtin and then revert back to it at the end of your test?

Comment: Your notion of scope doesn't apply to objects.  If you have a reference to a mutable object, no matter where that reference lives, it can mutate the object.

Comment: @JohnY very true, I hadn't considered that time was mutable, it's now clear *why* this was occurring. :)

Comment: I edited the question so that it actually describes what's actually being attempted. "Renaming" would mean using a different name for the same thing; this is *reassigning*, i.e., using the same name for a different thing. Also, `time` is a standard library module; its contents are **not** "builtin".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an object that you want to test against in this fashion you should use [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object). Pass in an object (in this case time) from the 'top' of the program. then you can unit-test individual functions or objects by passing in a mocked-out version.

Example:

```
# Function to be tested
def callSleep(timer):
    timer.sleep(5)

# Example usage
def main():
    import time
    timer = time

    callSleep(timer)

# Example test
def testFunction():


    class MockTimer:
        numCalled = 0
        withValue = 0
        def sleep(self, val):
            self.numCalled += 1
            self.withValue = val

    mockTimer = MockTimer()

    callSleep(mockTimer)

    print "Num called:", mockTimer.numCalled, "with value", mockTimer.withValue
```

Comment: So "passing time" was the solution. :)

Comment: Indeed! "Passing time by mocking objects".

Comment: We need to take care that `time` is passed everywhere which uses it **or** calls something which uses it (**or** calls something which calls something which uses it...)!

Answer (score 1):

I would follow @Joe's advice above, but below is a quick work-around to your problem.
As for why this happens, the reference to time.sleep is in the global scope, so the effect of replacing it is not restricted to the local scope.

```
import time
def test():
    old_sleep = time.sleep # Save a reference to the builtin
    time.sleep = "hello" #shouldn't this just set time.sleep locally?
    print 'Inside test:', time.sleep
    time.sleep = old_sleep # replace the reference

print time.sleep #prints <built-in function sleep>
test()
print time.sleep  #prints <built-in function sleep>
```

Comment: Is this known as ["monkey patching"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patching)? I don't think that the scope is quite the problem,rather it is because `time` is **mutable**. :)

Comment: Well you did originally ask why it seemed to be acting out of scope. And yes, I suppose this is monkey patching, since you don't modify your original source code but replace some libraries (temporarily) at run-time for testing.

Comment: I did! (I hadn't considered that `time` was mutable when I posted, in retrospect typing `time**.**sleep` should have given it away.) :)

Comment: Yep, I was wondering why you thought you could assign to time.sleep but didn't expect it to change!